# open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) but only on Android 10

Tags: android, kotlin, scoped-storage

When downloading a file from URL to the downloads directory it crashes on Android 10 Emulator:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/shareFile.mp3: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

This is how I download the file:

```
val storage = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    URL(soundURL).openStream().use { input ->
        FileOutputStream(File(storage.absolutePath, "shareFile.mp3")).use { output ->
            input.copyTo(output)
        }
    }
}
```

It crashes in the 4th line when calling FileOutputStream

I got both permissions granted: READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

On my Android 11 and 12 Devices everything works fine

Comment: Dont let your app crash by catching that exception. You can display a Toast then.

Comment: But... use first File.exists() and File.canRead() before.. you try to read the file. Adapt your code..

Comment: `When downloading a file from URL to the downloads directory ` There is no code that downloads anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you target Android 10, you need to set the value of **requestLegacyExternalStorage** to **true** in your app's manifest file:

```
    <application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    </application>
```

For more information, you can see here:

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#opt-out-in-production-app